# How to embed a muted, looping. auto-playing video that shows the close captions

Tags: wordpress, youtube-api

I used the youtube-api code I found and embedded it in a WordPress site. Essentially, it should autoplay an embedded Youtube video set to loop, that is muted and have CC. When I test it, it works except for the looping part. When I open the website on a different browser, nothing shows. I tried the  one as well but it does not let me mute the video. Help?!

```
<div id="muteYouTubeVideoPlayer"></div>

<script async src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script>
 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var player;
  player = new YT.Player('muteYouTubeVideoPlayer', {
    videoId: 'ofVRwYmc9WA', // YouTube Video ID
    width: 600,               // Player width (in px)
    height: 316,              // Player height (in px)
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 1,        // Auto-play the video on load
      controls: 1,        // Show pause/play buttons in player
      showinfo: 0,        // Hide the video title
      modestbranding: 1,  // Hide the Youtube Logo
      loop: 1,            // Run the video in a loop
      fs: 0,              // Hide the full screen button
      cc_load_policy: 1, // Hide closed captions
      iv_load_policy: 3,  // Hide the Video Annotations
      autohide: 0         // Hide video controls when playing
    },
    events: {
      onReady: function(e) {
        e.target.mute();
      }
    }
  });
 }

 // Written by @labnol
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally found someone to help me with this. We are using Powerpack for BeaverBuilder on WordPress.

You just need to add this code to the functions.php file of your current theme's folder:

```
add_filter( 'pp_video_embed_url', function($embed_url) {
    if ( false !== strpos( $embed_url, 'youtube' ) ) {
        $embed_url .= '&cc_load_policy=1';
    }
    
    return $embed_url;
});
```